# Can I type over an image and output as one image file?

Tags: html, image, html5-canvas

Is there a way in HTML5 Canvas that allows me to type out a sentence into a text box and it puts that text onto a banner image and then allows me to save that image as one with text?

The reason I want to do this is that it's for a flyer builder so people without any software to edit banners can just choose a banner template that I've made without any text and then type in there own and then output the banner to the flyer as one image.

I know that there are things Canvas can do like typing onto images but I want to know if its possible to output the image to a set destination.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

Answer (score 0):

I understand that your text - that the client can type - is drawn in the canvas?
If so - there is a way to save your entire canvas as an image.

you can use a div as a preview image of the drawing, and generate it like this:

```
// save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

// set canvasImg image src to dataURL
// so it can be saved as an image
document.getElementById('canvasImg').src = dataURL;
```

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GnH8E/

The first image is the canvas - the next is the image prewiew.